# Laravel: Sorting By Email Domain Name

Tags: php, database, laravel

Im using laravel and trying to figure out how run this query with fluent / eloquent (laravel)

```
select email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1) AS domain from epost order by domain desc;
```

My goal is to get the sorting by the domain namn rather than just sorting from the beginning of the string.

```
return Email::order_by('email', 'desc');
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work now using this string

```
return Epost::orderby(\DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1)"), "desc")->get();
```